# How to detect presence of Javascript in plain HTML using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xss

I have plain HTML code, without Javascript code in it.

How would you detect if any form of Javascript was injected in the HTML ?

The application generates HTML client side. And needs to validate it once it arrives on the server.

The goal is NOT to remove Javascript, but simply detect the presence of it.

Comment: Look for a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Sammitch - that's not sufficient - what about event-handlers?

Comment: Whatever your problem is could you explain it? Just by the way you phrased this question it sounds like whatever issue you're having you're probably thinking about it wrong.

Comment: @zfrisch I generate HTML client side. And need to validate it once it arrives on the server.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Is my question not legitimate ? Do I need to rephrase ? Any cues about what I've done wrong would be really helpful.

Comment: Does the application (you) generate the HTML or is it user-provided input?

Comment: @trincot The application generates the HTML, but the HTML is sent via POST to the server.

Comment: So then your application knows whether there is JavaScript included, right?

Comment: @trincot How can it know ? Anyone could POST evil HTML to my server, no ?

Comment: Anyone? So it ***is*** a user defined HTML then? ( I asked this...)

Comment: @trincot You could forge a POST request with evil html landing in $_POST['html']. oh ... important detail HTML is generated client side, by the application.

Comment: The standard answer is that you can try to mitigate it by validating and not allowing <script>, <body>, onclick, <a href=javascript://>. These would all require you to parse pretty thoroughly. Also you can escape the text, a.e. `<` = `&lt;`, `>` = `&gt;` that way even if they manage to get code submitted through it'll just display instead of execute. Instead of these things though you could use markup if it's for user generated content and simply disallow any actual HTML in the submission/generate it on the server side only.

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference in how to understand the question here. If the application is *supposed* to be the only one sending this to the server, or whether that application can take any input and send it. In the first case, the answer is simple: don't use HTML, but some key fields and let the server turn this into HTML. I suppose client and server know what they are doing.

Comment: @trincot The application allows users to customize HTML client side. Removing HTML would be great, but would also add a non negligible layer of complexity. I'm aiming at rejecting code with any suspected malicious injection.

Comment: Consider BB code or some other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what tools like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) are for. They break the input into tokens are run them against a white list.

This is safer than trying to find specific ways of inserting scripts into HTML, because there are tricks with malformed tags or non obvious attributes being used. See the [XSS Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Removing can be easier than detecting - just escape all the HTML etc. you get with `htmlspecialchars($string)`.

Alright, so this is a very interesting challenge:
First, check for all script tags, both capital and lowercase

```
<SCRIPT> <script> <sCrIPt>
```

Then, check for event handlers (onclick etc).

For this, we use DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
```

You can work all sorts of magic with DOM, I recommend reading their documentation. Check for any attributes with "on" in them